# Why is 'Class ... ' excuted only once when I created several instances?

Tags: python

I wrote codes as follow:

```
class a:
    print('hello')
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Adam'
b = a()
c = a()
```

There is only one 'hello' involved, although I creat instances of ***Class a*** twice.

```
hello
```

It seems that codeblocks below **'class a'** only be excuted one time even though I creat the instances twice. I am confused and I want to know how it works.

Comment: PS: the second codeblocks is the output.

Comment: `print('hello')` is executed when the class is defined, it has nothing to do with instances. When you create an instance, the `__init__()` method is executed.

Comment: You'll get that output even if you never create any instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside a class is only run once, when the program is run. After that, when you instantiate that class (`__init__`), the code inside the `__init__` method is called.

So, if you have a class like this:

```py
class A:
    print('A run')
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(f'A init {name}')
b = A('B')
c = A('C')
```

What is printed is:

```
A run
A init B
A init C
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I got it! But I still have and futher question about this problem (that is how and when the memebers in a class was bound to the instance) at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72095345/how-other-members-of-a-python-class-are-bound-to-the-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you initialize a new object, you do not call the code within its class.

You just call the `__init__`. Method.

When Python first "reads" your code, it runs it all. And if it encounters a `print()` statement, it will run it too. So, the python interpreter sees your code like this:

```py
# It runs this line - Just a comment, so nothing to run

# A class deceleration, let us look at its body and then store it
class a:
    # A print statement - I will run it. It does not add to the body, but I run all of the code I see
    print('hello')
    # This defines a method, so I will add it to the members of a
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Adam'

#  A new variable, I will call `__init__` - But just `__init__`
# I will not reparse the entire block, I will just jump to the location (Assuming JIT) where that function is stored and run it
b = a()
c = a()
```

So, we could rewrite your entire code like this:

```py
print("hello")
class a:
    def __init__():
         pass

b = a()
b.name = "Adam"
c = a()
c.name = "Adam"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it. But I still have and futher question about this problem (that is how and when the memebers in a class was bound to the instance) at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72095345/how-other-members-of-a-python-class-are-bound-to-the-instance)