# How other members of a python class are bound to the instance?

Tags: python

I wrote codes as follow:

```
class a:
    e = [1,2,3]
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Adam'

b = a()
c = a()
if b.e is c.e:
    print('they are same')
```

the outcome is:

```
they are same
```

It shows that b.e and c.e point to the same object. And if I use `id(a)`, it would return me an address in memory, showing that `a` has been created as an object.

When I want to creat an *instance* like `b=a()`, codes in the `__init__()` are excuted. But I am confused that when and how `e` (or other members like other methods) is bound to the instance?  (Actually in `__init__()` there is no lines like "let's bind `e` to this *instance*")

Comment: Because e is "bound to" the class, not the instance. Everything that is "bound to" a class is also available in every instance on that class.

Comment: class variables are created once for all objects so there ids are same. To check this you can simply change `b.e.append(3)` and check by printing `print(c.e)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**e** in your case is a class variable because it is declared directly under your class and not in the ***init***, this means that it is bound to the class and not to the instance of your object.

Answer (score 0):

**e** is a class variable attached to your class **a**

The usual way you should be accessing an instance variable is

```
class a:
  def __init__(self):
    self.e=[1,2,3]
    self.name = 'Adam'
```

Back into your example, add this line

a.e=[4,5,6]

and check how b.e and c.e have changed...

Answer (score 0):

because it's declared as a class variable, not an instance variable.

**Class variable:** Once copy of variable is shared between all instances.

**Instance variable:** Each instance has its own value and not shared between different instances of same class.

the following code will give you false.

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Adam'
        self.e = [1,2,3]

b = a()
c = a()
if b.e is c.e:
    print('they are same')
else:
    print("not the same")
```

output

```
"not the same"
```